cudnnGetConvolutionForwardWorkspaceSize with uint8
I have been trying to compare a custom-made cuda kernel that applies convolution operation on uint8 data (openCV cv::Mat) with well-known GPU libraries such as NPP, cuBLAS, cuDNN, arrayFire... I know, representing images with non-float variables is not common thing in GPGPU applications but I have to. While building the some code segments for cuDNN implementation, I could not figure out what is wrong with cudnnDataType_t configuration because I encountered CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED error all the time. In the documentation, definition of this error is:

The combination of the tensor descriptors, filter descriptor, and convolution descriptor is not supported for the specified algorithm.

Afterwards, I took a look at the data configurations supported for CC75 (cuDNN 9.5.1, GTX1660TI) and later. I decided the stick with UINT8_CONFIG even if it doesn't fell correct way to do it (because it doesn't identify the output image yDesc same as input xDesc). There is a snippet from the source:
cudnnHandle_t cudnn;
CHECK_CUDNN_ERROR(cudnnCreate(&cudnn));

cudnnTensorDescriptor_t input_descriptor, output_descriptor;
CHECK_CUDNN_ERROR(cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&input_descriptor));
CHECK_CUDNN_ERROR(cudnnSetTensor4dDescriptor(input_descriptor, CUDNN_TENSOR_NHWC, CUDNN_DATA_UINT8, 1, 1, rows, cols));
CHECK_CUDNN_ERROR(cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&output_descriptor));
CHECK_CUDNN_ERROR(cudnnSetTensor4dDescriptor(output_descriptor, CUDNN_TENSOR_NHWC, CUDNN_DATA_INT8, 1, 1, rows, cols));

cudnnFilterDescriptor_t f_descriptor;
CHECK_CUDNN_ERROR(cudnnCreateFilterDescriptor(&f_descriptor));
CHECK_CUDNN_ERROR(cudnnSetFilter4dDescriptor(f_descriptor, CUDNN_DATA_INT8, CUDNN_TENSOR_NHWC, 1, 1, 3, 3));

cudnnConvolutionDescriptor_t conv_descriptor;
CHECK_CUDNN_ERROR(cudnnCreateConvolutionDescriptor(&conv_descriptor));
CHECK_CUDNN_ERROR(cudnnSetConvolution2dDescriptor(conv_descriptor, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, CUDNN_CONVOLUTION, CUDNN_DATA_INT32));

size_t workspace_size = 0;
void* d_workspace = nullptr;


CHECK_CUDNN_ERROR(cudnnGetConvolutionForwardWorkspaceSize(
    cudnn, input_descriptor, f_descriptor, conv_descriptor, output_descriptor, CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_IMPLICIT_PRECOMP_GEMM , &workspace_size));

I can not figure out why am I encountering CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED at cudnnGetConvolutionForwardWorkspaceSize(...) ...
